# how can i write code to avoid same email of listed contacts

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

```
List <contact> con = new list<contact>
map<id,contact> cont = new map<id,contact>
For (cont em : con)
{
   con.put(em.email,em)
}
```

You have a list of Contacts. From this list, create a map of Email address and its corresponding list of contacts.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment read about [ask], and then [edit] your question so that the question and description agree with each other. On one hand, you're asking for deduplicating records, and on the other, you're asking for a map of list of contacts by email. Which one is it? What research have you done so far?

Comment: second thinng was my question i did that my question is for duplicating is jus sent the second one for refrence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note : If you are trying to avoid duplicate contacts by email id, you can use duplicate rules.

You can read in detail about duplicate rules [Here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_rules_map_of_reference.htm&type=5)

With reference to your comment you are asking for a map of list of contacts by email.
Here is the example.

```
Map<String,List<Contact>> emailToContacts = new Map<String,List<Contact>>();
for(Contact contactObj : contactList){
    if(!String.isBlank(contactObj.email)){
        if(emailToContacts.containsKey(contactObj.email)){
            emailToContacts.get(contactObj.email).add(contactObj);
        } else {
            emailToContacts.put(contactObj.email, new List<Contact>{ contactObj });
        }
    }
}
```